# How to move a window to another workspace in Xfce?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

The shortcut for "move windows to another workspace" in Xfce should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd>. But it doesn't work, there're no such shortcuts. Why, am I missing anything?

Comment: Why haven't you accepted clearkimura's answer? (Does it not work for you?)

Comment: OP never returned since 2016 to this date, but I just found an older screenshot as proof that Xfce had no such *shortcuts from before. See updated answer at below.

Answer (score 64):

There isn't any. By default, the action "Move window to left/right/up/down workspace" has no shortcuts set and that has not changed since Xfce 4.6 to this date. So the shortcuts might have been deprecated earlier or not adopted at all.

### But there should be

Those 'old' shortcuts were originally found in GNOME; the original author of this answer was aware of this, because they had been using GNOME 2 before switching to Xfce. The oldest known proof is shown by the screenshot with additional highlight as follows.

> [image: xfwm4 fill operation with additional highlight on unset move window shortcuts]
>
> Source: [Xfce 4.6 tour](https://www.xfce.org/about/tour46), screenshots by Jannis Pohlmann. The original screenshot was used to describe "fill operation" for xfwm4, which luckily showing the unset window shortcuts.

### Revive them anyway

To define shortcuts for the action "Move window to left/right/up/down workspace", user can configure in `xfwm4-settings` or navigate from Settings Manager in Xfce.

1. Go to **Settings Manager > Window Manager - Keyboard**
2. In the tab, **scroll down** until "Toggle fullscreen" entry and the relevant actions "Move window to..." are listed below it with empty column on the right
3. For the corresponding action "Move window to upper workspace", do either **double-click the empty column**, or select the row and click **Edit**
4. A small popup window will appear, then **press the shortcut keys of choice** to be assigned for previously selected action: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> for "Move window to upper workspace" and then the popup window will be closed
5. **Repeat step 3 and 4** for other actions, and finally click **Close** to finish.

### Additional notes

To this date, Wikipedia still note the 'old' shortcuts in the article of [Table of keyboard shortcuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) under "Window Management". That has changed since the introduction of GNOME 3, with most of the shortcuts have been redefined and [favours combination of **Super** key](https://wiki.gnome.org/Gnome3CheatSheet).

Comment: This answer deserves so many more upvotes than it has...

Answer (score 8):

Xfce 4.12 does have lots of shortcuts devoted to moving windows across workspaces.

1. There are shortcuts for moving a window to "previous workspace" and "next workspace", which correspond to left and right if your workspaces are in a row. **These keys both move the window and change the focus to the new workspace**. As is evident in the screenshot, there are no predefined shortcuts for moving a workspace "left", "right", "upper", or "bottom" (as noted by @clearkimura).
2. The shortcuts to move windows to specific numbered workspaces are predefined to work with the numeric keypad (noted by @aguaopd). **These keys move the window but do not change the focus to the new workspace.**

[image: xfce 4.12 window manager keyboard shortcuts]

Answer (score 4):

By default I have Ctrl+Alt+home and Ctrl+Alt+end to move windows to the next or to the previous workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Xfce 4.12 (at least in my Manjaro stable Illyria 18.0.2) does have default shortcuts. These are `Ctrl+Alt+1`, `Ctrl+Alt+2`, and so on. However, those numbers are the keypad numbers. (*[Source](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=43137#p43137)*)

So you can edit the shortcuts and press the normal numbers on your keyboard, and then they will work as many expect. Please note that they work either with the normal number keys or the keypad keys, but not both. Maybe there's a workaround for this.

Comment: Thank you, this works in Xubuntu 21.04 too