# How to add a command to an autosart that will use keyboard shortcuts or a command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, command, autostart

I have my favorite applications as an autostart and I want one to be automatically placed in another workspace. How can I do that? Are there any tips, tables with ready-made solutions?

The only thing that came to my mind is a shortcut that I would create with this tutorial
[How to move a window to another workspace in Xfce?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270334/how-to-move-a-window-to-another-workspace-in-xfce?newreg=b23322befb764fe596e016e09ce12fdb)

***Ctrl+Alt+Shift+↑***

only
but how to enter it here then? :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With [wmctrl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/wmctrl) you can say `wmctrl -r windowId -t desktopId` to change the workspace. `-d` and `-l` options list desktops and windows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check. And is it possible to write a script that will perform a certain movement from the keyboard ? (combination of keys to shortcut like ctr + shift + a?)

Comment: You can make a keyboard shortcut to invoke a script which uses `wmctrl` to move the window which has the input focus. Some Ubuntus have predefined keyboard shortcuts to move a window to another workspace (e.g. Shift+Super+Page Down, Shift+Super+Page Up).

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNOME Shell, you can install the [auto move windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/) extension.